# mysql_fetch_array with dot notation

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make a mysql_fetch_array from the following query

```
$query = "SELECT q.QUESTION AS Question FROM ANSWERS a, QUESTIONS q WHERE a.ID_Question = q.ID"

$contents="whatever, ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

    {
       $contents.=$row['Question'].", "; //what should I have here???
    }
```

But I have a doubt related to 'dot notation' I know that if the query said 'SELECT Pregunta' I'd put $row['Pregunta'] but in this case what should I put? I have tried it like it's here but echo $contents is just printing "whatever, ".

Of course I'm making all my DB connection, I tested all of this with a simpler query and it's working ok, as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM QUESTIONS WHERE ID_Usr=1";

$contents="whatever, ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

    {
       $contents.=$row['ID'].", ";
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about the dots, the prefixes won't affect the resulting array keys. For the rest of your doubts, you already got good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the other answer, there are additional flaws:

```
$query = "SELECT q.QUESTION AS Question FROM ANSWERS a, QUESTIONS q WHERE a.ID_Question = q.ID"
$result = mysql_query($query);

$contents="whatever, ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result ))
{
   $contents.=$row['Question'].", "; //what should I have here???
}
```

Mind the `mysql_query` which will give you a result set in `$result`which then can be iterated by `mysql_fetch...` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) if you want to access the columns by name.

Also, are you executing the `$query` anywhere? You can't just call `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_array` on the query string. You need to obtain a result from the database first.

Then again, the `mysql_` functions are deprecated, and you should really be using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mysql_query when using mysql_fetch_array. Your code should look like this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM QUESTIONS WHERE ID_Usr=1");

$contents="whatever, ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

    {
       $contents.=$row['ID'].", ";
    }
```

Hope this helps you